# Remove lines between paragraphs

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I am typesetting a Bible right now and the current status is that each verse is it's own paragraph, so that there is a newline after each verse. I want to have them as freeflowing text, is it possible to have paragraphs on the same line in indesign?

Answer (score 2):

You can run a Find/Replace from menu Edit → Find:

Find `^p` which is a paragraph end and replace it for a space  .

Answer (score 0):

Danielillo's answer is correct, but be advised in InDesign you cannot have multiple paragraphs on the same line. Default InDesign logic says every paragraph ends with a ¶ character and this is important because it also affects the way Paragraph Styles are applied in the formatting stage.

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to show these 'hidden' characters so you have a better view of where your paragraphs start and where they end.